# How do I search for special characters in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Clojure uses a number of special characters such as

- `^String`
- `#(xyz ...)`
- `%&`
- `#_(some form here)`
- `>!`

and many more.  How can I search for documentation for these special characters, given that Google *et al* mostly ignore special characters in web pages and search strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431515/use-of-in-clojure-function-parameter-definition/50431626#50431626) and others have raised an important topic:  it can often be difficult and frustrating to find documentation on special characters used in Clojure source code.

The first place to look is the Clojure docs themselves.  There is even a special page devoted to this topic:

- https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters

Many of the special characters are known as *Reader Literals*, which also have a documentation page:

- https://clojure.org/reference/reader

You can also find hints regarding special chars & their usage on:

- [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/)
- [Clojure-Doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/)

Finally, the search engine [SymbolHound.com](http://symbolhound.com) can search for special symbols that Google & others ignore.  For example, consider this Clojure code:

```
(defn lines
  "Given an open reader, return a lazy sequence of lines"
  [^java.io.BufferedReader reader]
  (take-while identity (repeatedly #(.readLine reader))))
```

How could we search for the meaning of `^java.io.BufferedReader` on the 3rd line?  If we go to SymbolHound and use the search string `clojure ^` we get back:

---

270 results found for ***clojure ^***

- [What are the usages for ^ and how can I get more information on it?](http://stackoverflow.com/question...nd-metadata-for-a-clojure-function)
- [Clojure syntax question re: #^](http://stackoverflow.com/question...nd-metadata-for-a-clojure-function)
- [How do I dynamically find metadata for a Clojure function?](http://stackoverflow.com/question...nd-metadata-for-a-clojure-function)

and many more answers.

Comment: SymbolHound.com does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

They're all described here:

https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters

You can also add more by contributing:

https://clojure.org/community/contributing_site

Comment: You were too fast for me.  I was trying to post a list of answers + SymbolHound.com